# Framework Kivy для разработки игр на Python-3.4

Tags: python, windows-7, kivy

Возможно ли прикрутить Kivy на Python-3.4 под Windows 7 таким образом, чтобы созданное приложение запускалось через интерпретатор напрямую ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Можно. Посмотрите [документацию](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#start-from-the-command-line-using-bash).